# Google Sheets - Query Count over multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I am trying to write a query formula in Google Sheets to count any appearances of a string, if another cell in that row begins with a specific string.

The table has hundreds of rows, but looks like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WEB – General | 1080 | 1080 | Michael | JPEG | 2 Mb |  |  |  |  |  |  | Display - Business | 1920 | 1080 | Alex | PNG | 2 |
| WEB – General | 560 | 660 | Martin | JPEG | 50 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Web - Mixed | 1920 | 1080 | Alex | PNG | 2 |
| Display – Mixed | 1700 | 300 | Matteo | JPEG |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Display - General | 1920 | 1080 | Bill | PNG | 2 |
| WEB – Business | 800 | 500 | Michael | JPEG |  | WEB - General | 800 | 500 | Alex | JPEG | 250kb |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| WEB - General | 1440 | 480 | Matteo | PNG |  | Display - Mixed | 700 | 600 | MATTEO | PNG |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| WEB – Mixed | 297 | 210 | Alex | JPEG | 4000 | WEB - General | 297 | 210 | Maluma | JPEG | 4000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Here Columns A - F and G - L belong together in each case.

Now I want to count any appearance of the name Alex in column `D` & `J`, if the corresponding category column (`A` & `G`) begins with `WEB`.

So I wrote the following formula:

```
=QUERY({A2:L481};"
SELECT COUNT(Col1) WHERE ((LOWER(Col4) LIKE '%alex%' AND LOWER(Col1) LIKE '%web%') 
OR (LOWER(Col10) LIKE '%alex%' AND LOWER(Col7) LIKE '%web%') 
OR (LOWER(Col16) LIKE '%alex%' AND LOWER(Col13) LIKE '%web%'))";0)
```

Unfortunately the sum is not correct.

Maybe I just can't see through it any more because I'm a bit overtired. But I just can't find the mistake.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards
Lars

Comment: Query will count unique rows from given data matching the arguments, get separate query to count of each scenario then sum them up. Else skip using query formula.

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
=sum(index(if((left(A2:O;3)="web")*(D2:R="alex");1;)))
```

[image]

**IF** `Alex` needs to be also partial-matched to say `Alex Dunphy` and `Alexander` as well:

```
=sum(index(if((left(A2:O,3)="web")*(iferror(search("alex",D2:R))),1,)))
```

**IF** `Alex` needs to be also partial-matched to say `Alex Dunphy` and **NOT** `Alexander`:

```
=sum(index(if((left(A2:O,3)="web")*(iferror(regexmatch(D2:R,"(?i)\balex\b"))),1,)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed help. I will try around with your formula. 
But I will also take into consideration to work with separate queries for each scenario and sum them up as mentioned by DhamankarTejas.